# Centering left-aligned-to-longest-TextView TextViews not working in LinearLayout with wrap content

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout

I want to create a layout where there are multiple lines with various lengths of text. All the texts are centered. The starting point of the centered longest text will serve as a basis. Then, the other texts, which are shorter, will no longer be centered but will be aligned left to the starting point of the longest text.

To achieve this in a ConstraintLayout, I have created a LinearLayout that is centered and has a width of `wrap_content`. Then, inside the LinearLayout, I have multiple `TextView`s also with width `wrap_content`. I expect the LinearLayout to expand itself (in width), up to the width of the ConstraintLayout (which has the width of the device), to ensure that its children `TextView`s do not wrap *unless* the text is longer that the screen width (which, in my particular case, is impossible). The preview of the Android Studio editor shows that this happens as I expected. However, upon running on my device and using `Tools > Layout Inspector` on Android Studio, the LinearLayout does not expand itself in width even when there is much space remaining.

Here is my XML code for the layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="user"
            type="com.mobile.githubuser.model.GithubUser" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/act_details_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:title="@string/act_user_details_toolbar_title"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Toolbar" />

        <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
            android:id="@+id/shapeableImageView"
            style="@style/Widget.GithubUser.ShapeableImageView.Circular"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/user_details_avatar_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/user_details_avatar_size"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/keyline_5"
            android:src="@{user.avatar}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/act_details_toolbar" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/materialTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/keyline_4"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/keyline_4"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/keyline_4"
            android:text="@{user.name}"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline2"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorOnBackground"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/shapeableImageView"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
            tools:text="April Ludgate" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/materialTextView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/keyline_4"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/keyline_2"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/keyline_4"
            android:text="@{`@` + user.username}"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceSubtitle2"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorOnBackground"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/materialTextView"
            tools:text="\@april_ludgate" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/keyline_4"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/keyline_5"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/keyline_4"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/materialTextView2">

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/materialTextView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/drawable_company"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/keyline_2"
                android:text="@{`Company\t\t: ` + user.company}"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody1"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorOnBackground"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/materialTextView2"
                tools:text="\Company\t\t: Google, Inc." />

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/materialTextView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/keyline_0"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/drawable_location"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/keyline_2"
                android:text="@{`Location\t\t\t: ` + user.location}"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody1"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorOnBackground"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/materialTextView3"
                tools:text="Location\t\t\t: Pittsburgh, PA, USA" />

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/materialTextView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/keyline_0"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/drawable_repository"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/keyline_2"
                android:text="@{`Repository\t: ` + user.repository}"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody1"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorOnBackground"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/materialTextView4"
                tools:text="Repository\t: 2" />

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/materialTextView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/keyline_0"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/drawable_follower"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/keyline_2"
                android:text="@{`Followers\t\t: `}"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody1"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorOnBackground"
                addNumberToText="@{user.followers}"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/materialTextView5"
                tools:text="Followers\t\t: 1029" />

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/materialTextView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/keyline_0"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/drawable_following"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/keyline_2"
                android:text="@{`Following\t\t: `}"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody1"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorOnBackground"
                addNumberToText="@{user.following}"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/materialTextView6"
                tools:text="Following\t\t: 101" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Here is what my editor preview is showing (what I want).

[image: What I want]

Here is the tool inspector showing the problem.

[image: Problem]

As you can see on the second image, the `TextView` wrap to two lines when there is space (to the left and right) of the `LinearLayout`. I expect the `LinearLayout` to take as much space as possible but the least amount of space possible to still display all the `TextView` in one line each. Using `android:maxLines=1` and `android:singleLine=true` causes the text to be cut off and to be ellipsis-ed respectively; I do not want this. What is causing this problem? If achieving what I want this way is impossible, how can I achieve what I described (without using a fixed value, e.g. margin and guideline to align the `TextView`s)?

*Not related to question: why doesn't my `MaterialTextView` display properly in my Android Studio eidtor preview?*

Comment: Why not just set the width to match parent?

Comment: @tyczj Which width? LinearLayout?

Comment: the children of the linear layout. It seems to me that the images and padding of the text next to them are causing the issue though. Instead of setting the drawable in the textview just create an `ImageView` and have the text be text with no images and realign everything

Comment: @tyczj Setting the width of the `TextView` **with** the drawable present causes the text to be centered, but causes the drawable to be aligned to the left side. I want the drawable (icon) and the text to be there side by side. However, I'll try your suggestion on using separate `ImageView` and `TextView` to create the line. Although I'd like it better if I could just use one `TextView`.

Comment: @tyczj I have just tried your suggestion. Here's what I tried exactly: I replaced all the inner `TextView`s to `LinearLayout`s. In each `LinearLayout`, I have a `TextView` and an `ImageView`. The inner `LinearLayout` and its children all have a width of `wrap_content`. Instead of using padding on the `ImageView`, I used a `marginStart` on the `TextView` to create a space. The result is the same as the problem described above (the second image). I also tried setting the inner `LinearLayout` to `match_parent`, but this did not change anything.

Comment: Does removing the LinearLayout's marginStart/marginEnd change anything? If these are too large, the LinearLayout is forced to a maximum width and therefore has to wrap its children

Comment: @A.Kuchinke I did explain the logical reasoning behind my solution and that in the situation you described, the LinearLayout will wrap its children. However, as can be seen in the second image, there is still much space on the left and right sides (the LinearLayout **can** still expand; I tried setting its width manually and it did work). Sadly, no, setting both the marginStart/End to 0 did not change anything.

Comment: If you remove `\t` from the TextViews, does it still wrap the same way?

Comment: @PawelLaskowski Wow, it doesn't. Why does this happen? How does `\t` affect layouting?

Comment: I suspect `\t` may cause issues when calculating width for `wrap_content`. I'm not sure how to fix it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [@Pawel Laskowski's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62537951/linearlayout-with-width-wrap-content-does-not-expand-and-causes-its-children-tex?noredirect=1#comment110597787_62537951), it is the tab character (`\t`) that is causing problems in the layout. Simply erasing the tab characters and replacing them with several spaces work. However, as the font I am using is not monospaced, the colon part isn't aligned perfectly.

An alternative solution is to separate the one TextView per line into two TextViews. This also works in my favor because now, I can provide a string literal (e.g. `Company`, `Location`, etc.) in multiple languages and add the dynamically generated content (from the data-binding `user`) to the overall displayed text. Then, after all the separations, place the TextViews inside a ConstraintLayout, **replacing** the original LinearLayout. Now, our structure is the following (for the problematic section).

```
ConstraintLayout
  |__ TextView (first part for row 1)
  |__ TextView (second part for row 1)
  |__ ...
  |__ TextView (first part for row n)
  |__ TextView (second part for row n)
```

Then, create a barrier with the direction `end` referencing all the first parts of each row. Position all the second parts of each row relative to the barrier and add some `marginStart` to create space between the first part and the second part. The second part contains the colon and the dynamically-generated content.

Here's the final XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="user"
            type="com.mobile.githubuser.model.GithubUser" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/act_details_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:title="@string/act_user_details_toolbar_title"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Toolbar" />

        <com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
            android:id="@+id/shapeableImageView"
            style="@style/Widget.GithubUser.ShapeableImageView.Circular"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/user_details_avatar_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/user_details_avatar_size"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/keyline_5"
            android:src="@{user.avatar}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/act_details_toolbar" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/materialTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/keyline_4"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/keyline_4"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/keyline_4"
            android:text="@{user.name}"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceHeadline2"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorOnBackground"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/shapeableImageView"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
            tools:text="April Ludgate" />

        <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
            android:id="@+id/materialTextView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/keyline_4"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/keyline_2"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/keyline_4"
            android:text="@{`@` + user.username}"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceSubtitle2"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorOnBackground"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/materialTextView"
            tools:text="\@april_ludgate" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/keyline_4"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/keyline_5"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/keyline_4"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/materialTextView2">

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/materialTextView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/drawable_company"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/keyline_2"
                android:text="@string/company_label"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody1"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorOnBackground"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/materialTextView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/keyline_0"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/drawable_location"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/keyline_2"
                android:text="@string/location_label"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody1"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorOnBackground"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/materialTextView3" />

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/materialTextView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/keyline_0"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/drawable_repository"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/keyline_2"
                android:text="@string/repository_label"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody1"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorOnBackground"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/materialTextView4" />

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/materialTextView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/keyline_0"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/drawable_follower"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/keyline_2"
                android:text="@string/followers_label"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody1"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorOnBackground"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/materialTextView5" />

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/materialTextView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/keyline_0"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/drawable_following"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/keyline_2"
                android:text="@string/following_label"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody1"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorOnBackground"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/materialTextView6" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
                android:id="@+id/barrier2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:barrierDirection="right"
                app:constraint_referenced_ids="materialTextView3,materialTextView4,materialTextView5,materialTextView6,materialTextView7"/>

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/materialTextView8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/keyline_2"
                android:text="@{`: ` + user.company}"
                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody1"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorOnBackground"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/materialTextView3"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/barrier2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/materialTextView3"
                tools:text=": Google, Inc." />

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/materialTextView9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/keyline_2"
                android:text="@{`: ` + user.location}"
                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody1"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorOnBackground"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/materialTextView4"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/barrier2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/materialTextView4"
                tools:text=": Pittsburgh, PA, U.S.A." />

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/materialTextView10"
                formatNumberToTextWithColon="@{user.repository}"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/keyline_2"
                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody1"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorOnBackground"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/materialTextView5"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/barrier2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/materialTextView5"
                tools:text=": 1,234" />

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                android:id="@+id/materialTextView11"
                formatNumberToTextWithColon="@{user.followers}"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/keyline_2"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody1"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorOnBackground"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/materialTextView6"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/barrier2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/materialTextView6"
                tools:text=": 304" />

            <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                formatNumberToTextWithColon="@{user.following}"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/keyline_2"
                android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceBody1"
                android:textColor="?attr/colorOnBackground"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/barrier2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/materialTextView7"
                tools:text=": 1" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```